# Submit form fails

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a page that which is an exam page,it selects all MCQ questions with their answers...
and in server side page load i add div.innerHtml += "html tags " + question + radio buttons containing answers and it keeps selecting from database till all questions are rendered in client side, the thing is i add all these questions and tags in form and in its end there is a input submit button which should submit all radio buttons values but even if i set form action i cant get the radio buttons values...

Here is some code :

```
using (SqlDataReader sr1 = command1.ExecuteReader())
{
    cc.InnerHtml = "<form id=\"form2\" name=\"form2\" method=\"post\" action=\"\">";
    while (sr1.Read())
    {
        i++;
        iString = i.ToString();
        questionText = sr1["text"].ToString();
        question_first_wrong_answer = sr1["first_wrong_answer"].ToString();
        question_second_wrong_answer = sr1["second_wrong_answer"].ToString();
        question_right_answer = sr1["right_answer"].ToString();
        questionValue = (int)sr1["value"];
        c = answerPos.Next(0, 10);

        cc.InnerHtml += "<span>" + iString + "- " + questionText +"</span>"
                     + "<br />"
                     + "<table style=\"width:77%; margin-left: 47px;\">"
                     + "<tr>"
                     + "    <td style=\"width: 210px\">"
                     + " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"question" + iString + "a\" value=\"" + question_first_wrong_answer + "\" />" + question_first_wrong_answer + "</td>"
                     + "<td style=\"width: 210px\">"
                     + "<input type=\"radio\"  name=\"question" + iString + "a\" value=\"" + question_second_wrong_answer + "\" />" + question_second_wrong_answer + "</td>"
                     + "<td style=\"width: 210px\">"
                     + "<input type=\"radio\"  name=\"question" + iString + "a\" value=\"" + question_right_answer + "\" />" + question_right_answer + "</td>"
                     + "</tr>"
                     + "</table>"
                     + "<br />";

    }
    sr1.Close();
    cc.InnerHtml += "<input id=\"Submit1\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />"
                 + "</form>";
}
```

Comment: I think if you show the resultant HTML it would be very helpful.

Comment: Why are you building the whole form 'dynamically'. Why not just put the form in ASP.NET (HTML) and put the question and answers in on run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not Use InnerHtml. Its Wrong.
   Use Inbuild `HtmlPage` Class

Use Like this for Example

```
Page.Controls.Add( 
  new LiteralControl(@"<html>\r\n<body>\r\n
    <h1>Welcome to my Homepage!</h1>\r\n"));
HtmlForm Form1 = new HtmlForm();
Form1.ID = "Form1";
Form1.Method = "post";
Form1.Controls.Add(
  new LiteralControl("\r\nWhat is your name?\r\n"));
TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();
TextBox1.ID = "txtName";
Form1.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
Form1.Controls.Add(
  new LiteralControl("\r\n<br />What is your gender?\r\n"));
DropDownList DropDownList1 = new DropDownList();
DropDownList1.ID = "ddlGender";
ListItem ListItem1 = new ListItem();
ListItem1.Selected = true;
ListItem1.Value = "M";
ListItem1.Text = "Male";
DropDownList1.Items.Add(ListItem1);
ListItem ListItem2 = new ListItem();
ListItem2.Value = "F";
ListItem2.Text = "Female";
DropDownList1.Items.Add(ListItem2);
ListItem ListItem3 = new ListItem();
ListItem3.Value = "U";
ListItem3.Text = "Undecided";
DropDownList1.Items.Add(ListItem3);
Form1.Controls.Add(
  new LiteralControl("\r\n<br /> \r\n"));
Button Button1 = new Button();
Button1.Text = "Submit!";
Form1.Controls.Add(Button1);
Form1.Controls.Add(
  new LiteralControl("\r\n</body>\r\n</html>"));
Controls.Add(Form1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the server form element (`<form runat="server"` ). If that is present, this new form is discarded.

Also you are using the same name for different input controls.

```
name=\"question" + iString + "a\" value=\""
```

So you need to have unique names for the radio too.

Comment: I am reading elements from database and while it reads it keeps incrementing " i " which i convert to iString which is added to every " group " of radio buttons so every question have 3 answers which have same name but different values...but this isnt the problem...when i click submit button it does nothing...so i wanna know how to get radio buttons values ?

Comment: how many forms do you have? are you having nested froms? (ie form in form)

Comment: no...just 1 form but a lot of questions with their radio buttons...i might think i should add these controls using asp controls and not with pure html